# Secondary Sorting : When does the sorting of values happen?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata, reducers

I have implemented secondary sorting for my requirement. But I need some clarity on the internal working of the same.

Given that sorting happens on the map side. I assume that all the (k,V) pairs in the spill files are ordered by keys. In our case, the composite keys.

I would like to know how the values belonging the same key from many mapfiles come in a specific order (As specified in the SortComparator) to reduce fucntion every single time.

If sorting happens on the map side and merging is done on the reducer side. How and when the values belonging to key from many map files are arranged in a particular order before the reduce function starts ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Values are not sorted by default, only the keys. However, you can override `Partitioner`, `SortComparator` and `GroupingComparator` in specific way that makes hadoop framework to sort both keys and values in any way you like. (Example of such setup can be found in my [article](http://gudok.xyz/ph/ep1-join/)). Beware that because typically value objects are much larger, jobs which order both keys and values will run for much longer than with only keys sorting.

Keys are sorted in both mappers and reducers:

1. mappers sort KV pairs for every reducer output resulting in that each output file is sorted according to SortComparator
2. reducer takes a lot of sorted files from mappers and merges them together, providing input to reduce() invocations

Values come to reduce() in some unspecified order by default. Generally, it will depend on everything: order in which you emit key/value pairs in map, order in which hadoop decides to merge files, sort algorithm used and so on.

Comment: :: Thanks for the response. I am able to find the reduce input values to be ordered as specified in the SortComparator. So i was curious to know if once again Sorting happens on the reducer side after merging many mapfiles. There has to be some logic or algorithm that makes secondary sorting possible which restricts the reducer input to be of a specific order. This cannot happen if sorting is only on the map end right ? Kindly correct me if my understanding is wrong.

Comment: There are no separate primary and secondary sort. There is only single sort. And it is done in both mappers and reducers. By default it orders KV pairs only by keys, leaving values in some unspecified order. But you can make it to sort both keys and values. Order of actions in hadoop: 1) map partitions (Partitioner) emitted KV pairs, 2) map sorts (SortComparator) output for each partition, 3) reduce collects all outputs from mappers, 4) reducer merges (SortComparator once again) them; 5) reducer slices (GroupingComparator) merged output and feeds data into your `reduce()` implementation.